# Question on understanding vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm new to vector spaces and I know that if I'm dealing with objects that can be added and scaled and which follow some axioms then they are part of a vector space. I always thought vectors were arrows, and know I know that this is just one case of vectors. But when I think about arrows or column vectors which exist in the plane I believe their origin is not defined so when talking about $\mathbb R^2$ as a vector space for example one of the elements is $(2,4)$  for example.. as a point this has an origin but if it were considered a vector it has no origin I believe as the vector just represents a displacement. I'm confused about whether my last point is correct and whether when you think about $ \mathbb R^2$ as a vector space there is any origin or whether all the elements just represent displacements.

Comment: The origin is the vector $(0,\dots,0)$. You are probably confused between mathematical vectors and free vectors as used in physics.

Comment: The teaching of  mathematical definitions at lower levels of the education system often ranges from poor to nonsensical. E.g. "A vector has length and direction". So does a bus. Have you tried Wikipedia for the definitions of Group, Abelian Group, Field, and Vector Space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to be on the right track in your thinking.

I would not say that a "vector" is necessarily a displacement, because there are vector spaces that don't have an obvious geometric interpretation like that.
You can, however, define a particular vector space by taking the displacements between pairs of points in an $n$-dimensional Euclidean geometric space.
If we give the geometric space Cartesian coordinates,
each vector can be completely described by the differences between the corresponding coordinates in a "to" point and a "from" point.
So you can get the vector $(2,4)$ -- the *same* vector $(2,4)$ -- either as the displacement from $(0,0)$ to $(2,4)$ or as the displacement from $(17,23)$ to $(19,27)$ or as the displacement between any of an infinite number of other pairs of points.

And that seems to be the kind of vector "in the plane" that you're talking about.

The origin of Cartesian coordinates for the points in the Euclidean geometry is not a member of the vector space and doesn't have any special "privilege" with respect to that space. There is a "zero vector" in the vector space but calling it an "origin" seems misleading to me; rather, it is something you can add another vector as many times as you want without and get a result equal to the original other vector.

There is, however, a special one-to-one correspondence between the vectors of that vector space and the set of points in the geometric space from which we generated the vectors: the correspondence between a vector and a point with the exact same coordinates.
It happens (for obvious reasons) that the vector that gives the displacement from the origin of the geometric space to a point $P$ is also the same vector that has the exact same coordinates as $P$; this is sometimes called the position vector of $P$.
But the fact that this vector has such a relationship to a point does not give the vector a particular location in the geometric space. This kind of vector is still defined by the displacement between two points, and it's still just a displacement.

---

I should mention that there are others way to get a vector space over
$\mathbb R^2$. One way is to just define a vector abstractly as an ordered pair of numbers
and set up the appropriate definitions of addition and scalar multiplication.
There doesn't *need* to be any geometric interpretation.
What I mean by my earlier remarks is that the the usual geometric interpretation, when there *is* one, is the one you described in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Vectors are by definition just elements of a vector space, i.e. elements of a certain type of set. If the vector space is $V = \mathbb{R}^n$, a vector is just a point in $n$ coordinates. I would not imagine vectors as arrows or displacements, but you can still sort of say that every vector in a vector space is a displacement of the zero vector given by translating exactly by the given vector.

Usually, the point $(0,\dots,0) \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is what you would call origin.

Answer (score 0):

Your confusion is justified and can be traced back all the way to how we think of the number line. When we draw a number line and we consider for example the number $2$ attached to a point on it, what do we have in mind, the **geometric point** corresponding to 2, or the **length** of the segment that starts at the origin and ends at that point? Most of the time the answer is that we think of the numbers as points on the number line. But in reality, to do algebra with these points, we really need to attach the meaning of length to them. That means we need to think of them as vectors. The same when studying vector spaces: when we say that $(2,4)$ is an element of the vector space $\mathbb R^2$ we need to interpret the numbers $2$ and $4$ as lengths, not geometric points. By default, the length is measured from the origin. So if we write $\mathbf{v}=(2,4)$ we think of it as as an arrow with the tail at the origin and the head at the point $(2,4)$ (note the clash of notation: sometimes $(2,4)$ is a point, sometimes it's a vector...). We cannot do algebra with points: we can only do it with vectors. If we want to have a geometric picture of vectors, we need to think of them as arrows, because the meaning of the components of the vector $(2,4)$ is that of length. As a consequence, it doesn't matter where the tail is. So the arrow that has tail at the point $P_1=(1,1)$ and head at the point $P_2=(3,5)$, as a vector, is identical to $\mathbf{v}$. We can in this case use the notation $\mathbf{v}=\overline{P_1P_2}$, to emphasize the 
geometric picture we have in mind. But if write $\mathbf{v}=(2,4)$, we always assume that the tail is at the origin.